# java util logging multiple handlers causing repetitive log messages

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I have a situation where multiple handlers are being set into a single logger. Each Handler replaces sensitive information from being logged.

Please see the below SSCCE

```
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class TestLogging {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(A.class.getName());
        logger.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler(){
            {
                setFormatter(new Formatter() {
                    @Override
                    public String format(LogRecord record) {
                        return record.getMessage().replaceAll("method","replacing method");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        logger.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler(){
            {
                setFormatter(new Formatter() {
                    @Override
                    public String format(LogRecord record) {
                        return record.getMessage().replaceAll("Logging","replacing logging");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

        A a =new A();
        a.method();
    }


    public static class A{

        private static final Logger LOGGER=Logger.getLogger(A.class.getName());

        public void method(){
            LOGGER.info("\nLogging from inside method");
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the output to be "replacing logging from inside replacing method", but instead I get an output like this

```
Logging from inside replacing method
replacing logging from inside method
```

How do I merge both these handlers into one, if I find another has already been set?

Comment: Not sure why this is being voted to be closed down. Its courteous to say why this needs to be closed or even while down voting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design handlers are not supposed to be chained or merged, as their main purpose is to perform the final LogRecord handling, like writing into file. I suggest to change the approach a bit and merge formatters instead of handlers. Please take a look at the following example:

```
public class TestLogging {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(A.class.getName());
    FormatHandler handler = new FormatHandler();
    logger.addHandler(handler);

    handler.addFormatter(new Formatter() {
        @Override
        public String format(LogRecord record) {
            return record.getMessage().replaceAll("method", "replacing method");
        }
    });

    handler.addFormatter(new Formatter() {
        @Override
        public String format(LogRecord record) {
            return record.getMessage().replaceAll("Logging", "replacing logging");
        }
    });
    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

    A a = new A();
    a.method();
}

public static class FormatHandler extends ConsoleHandler {

    private List<Formatter> formatters = new ArrayList<>();

    public FormatHandler() {
        setFormatter(new CompositeFormatter());
    }

    public void addFormatter(Formatter f) {
        formatters.add(f);
    }

    class CompositeFormatter extends Formatter {
        @Override
        public synchronized String format(LogRecord record) {
            String modifiedMessage;
            for(Formatter formatter : formatters){
                modifiedMessage = formatter.format(record);
                record.setMessage(modifiedMessage);
            }
            return record.getMessage();
        }
    }
}

public static class A {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(A.class.getName());

    public void method() {
        LOGGER.info("\nLogging from inside method");
    }
    }
}
```

It performs the output you want.

Comment: Thanks!.. Will change my design now.. :)

Comment: Hey.. I had a question though.. Can't we add a ConsoleHandler and a FileHandler to a logger and format the message as well?.. I have replaced by handler to be a FileHandler which will be used in the production systems. But I wanted to log it to the console on my developer machine

Comment: Why not?) Just add the CompositeFormatter to the FileHandler as well.

Comment: Then get back to the same issue where the same messages are being logged twice within the console itself

Comment: I see. If you want to use different logger implementation in dev and production environment, then introduce some kind of a "dev mode" flag or build profile. Otherwise your app will never know which kind of environment it's running in.

Comment: I am doing that.. thought I could 'tee' the log to the console in the dev env while logging to a file in both dev and prod. log4j does this quite easily. Not sure why JUL doesn't support this. Unfortunately I am stuck with JUL since jersey rest client does only JUL.

Comment: You can get rid of JUL at all, it's actualy what I did in the first place when utilized Jersey client myself. JUL may be easily bridged to SLF4J, which, in turn, may use Log4J as a backend. Take a look at http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html